# How to start a new minibuffer from the minibuffer (non-recursive)

Tags: emacs

Sometimes, I press the wrong combination of keys and get the wrong minibuffer. I'd like to kill my current minibuffer and open a new one by just pressing the key-combination for the desired minibuffer option. How do I do that?

Comment: A minibuffer opens as a result of various functions which require input by the user.  There are too many possibilities to simply open a new minibuffer.  Do you mean cancel the current function and launch the same function again?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood then. Yes, I'd just like to be able to do M-x when I do M-w and vice versa - two minibuffer functions I often mix up.

Comment: In what sense is `M-w` (`kill-ring-save`) a minibuffer function? Also, can you elaborate further on what exactly is the desired behaviour?

Comment: Sorry, I have remapped C-w to something else.

Comment: The desired behavior is that when I am in a function requiring input from the minibuffer and I want to open another function using the minibuffer I can just press the keys to start the latter function and it will start. I see this as much better standard behavior, instead of the annoying "attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a good idea or not.

```el
(setq enable-recursive-minibuffers t)

(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'my-minibuffer-unrecursion)

(defun my-minibuffer-unrecursion ()
  (when (> (minibuffer-depth) 1)
    (run-with-timer 0 nil 'my-interactive-command
                    this-command current-prefix-arg)
    (abort-recursive-edit)))

(defun my-interactive-command (cmd arg)
  (let ((current-prefix-arg arg))
    (call-interactively cmd)))
```